# How to format a string for proper display in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview, string-formatting

I have a FAQ section in my app, but I have to present it in a certain way using a non-editable UITextView. Just like below,

1. How can I cancel a recording?

   A. You can cancel a recording while it is in progress by pressing the cancel (red ‘X’) button

   ```
     in the center of the speaker on the recording screen. The audio recording 
     will not be saved.
   ```

But the problem is as you can see the has to be shown with some padding and the next line should start just below the answer line **"not below the A"**. And there's a huge document of questions so I cannot format it manually. And it for both iPhone and iPad so I the UITextView width differs. Is there any solution to this kind of problem ?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but try a tab like @"First line\n\tSecond Line with tab\n\t\tThird line with two tabs". So "\t" is a tab and "\n" is line break

Comment: @DavidG. At first I thought of that, but the width of UITextView comes into picture which is different for both iphone and ipad. So I can't use that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use `NSAttributedString` and the `NSParagraphStyle` combined with `NSParagraphAttributeName`.

Here is a example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

int indent1 = 0;
int indent2 = 20;
int indent3 = 2*indent2;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *styleTitleByNumber = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[styleTitleByNumber setFirstLineHeadIndent:indent1];
[styleTitleByNumber setHeadIndent:indent1];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *styleTitleByLetter = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[styleTitleByLetter setFirstLineHeadIndent:indent2];
[styleTitleByLetter setHeadIndent:indent2];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *styleSimpleText = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[styleSimpleText setFirstLineHeadIndent:indent3];
[styleSimpleText setHeadIndent:indent3];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName 
                         value:styleTitleByNumber
                         range:rangeOfTitleByNumber];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName 
                          value:styleTitleByLetter 
                          range:rangeOfTitleByLetter];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName 
                          value:styleSimpleText
                          range:rangeOfSimpleText];

[yourTextView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Now, depending how is formatted your initial text, I leave you the way to know where to apply which style (for the `NSRange` parameter), or you can also, if the different parts are separated apply a direct effect on the `NSAttributedString`, and then combine them all.